# Forms, Model, and updating with current user

Tags: django, python-3.x

I think this works, but I came across a couple of things before getting it to work that I want to understand better, so the question. It also looks like other people do this a variety of ways looking at other answers on stack overflow. What I am trying to avoid is having the user to have to select his username from the pulldown when creating a new search-profile. The search profile model is:

```
class Search_Profile(models.Model):
    author_of_profile = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True)
    keyword_string = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    other_stuff = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

The form I ended up with was:

```
class Search_Profile_Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Search_Profile
        fields = [ 'keyword_string', 'other_stuff']
```

Where I deliberately left out 'author_of_profile' so that it wouldn't be shown or need to be validated. I tried hiding it, but then the form would not save to the model because a field hadn't been entered.  If I was o.k. with a pulldown I guess I could have left it in.

I didn't have any issues with the HTML while testing for completeness:

```
  <form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.author_of_profile}}
    {{ form.keyword_string }}
    {{ form.other_stuff }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save and Return to Home Page">
  </form>
```

And the View is where I ended up treating the form and the model separated, saving the form first, then updating the model, which is where I think there might be some other way people do it.

```
def New_Profile(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = Search_Profile_Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post=form.save(commit=False)
            # here is where I thought I could update the author of profile  field  somehow with USER
            # but If I include the author_of_profile field in the form it seems I can't.
            post.save()
            #So instead I tried to update the author_of profile directly in the model
            current_profile=Search_Profile.objects.last()
            current_profile.author_of_profile=request.user
            current_profile.save()
            return(redirect('home'))
    else:
        form=Search_Profile_Form()
    return render(request, 'mainapp/New_Profile.html', {'form': form})
```

So a few questions:
For the Foreign Key in author_of_profile field, is it better to use blank=True, or null=True 
I ended up using   request.user   rather than  importing from django.contrib.auth.models import User is there any difference?
My real question though, is the above a reasonable way to get form data and update the database with that data and the user? Or am I missing some other way that is more build in?

Comment: Well, to answer one of my own questions, if I use null=True instead of blank=True then I can add more fields to the database, without complaints from Django.

Answer (score 0):

```
post=form.save()
current_profile.author_of_profile=request.user
post.save()

return(redirect('home'))
```

try something like this. save the form to db then change the author again. `save(commit=False)` will not save the date to db immediately.

Comment: thanks, I tried it, but the author_of_profile field in the database doesn't get updated that way. I think it is because the  author_of_profile field is not included in class Meta, and when I do include it, then it displays the selector box  on the html.